# avoid showing menu on button click

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

In my application there is a button and when the button is clicked, the context menu poping up.  How can I avoid having the context menu show up?

```
protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int context){
    menu.add(_imageMenuItem);
    super.makeMenu(menu, context);
}

class ImageMenuItem extends MenuItem {      
    ImageMenuItem() {
        super("Login Screen", 0, 0);            
    }
    public boolean onMenu(int i) {
        return false;
    }

    public void run() {
        UiApplication app = (UiApplication) getApplication();
        app.pushScreen(new LoginScreen());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

have you added style to the ButtonField via the constructor?

```
ButtonField button = 
    new ButtonField("text", Field.H_CENTRE|ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
```

Comment: Yea Adil,I added style to the ButtonField via the constructor
I late to comment since I am out of station sorry

Comment: btnSave=new ButtonField("Save",FIELD_HCENTER | FIELD_HCENTER);

Comment: Thanks Adil,I got the solution ....when I added ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK to the consructor .

Comment: I have the same problem for a verticalfield manager, Do you have idea to resolve it?

Comment: My application uses a vertical field manager: scrollingRegion = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT| VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR|USE_ALL_WIDTH);CustomField customField = new CustomField(hashtable, int);scrollingRegion.add(customField);   
    add(scrollingRegion); My app run in the way that user click in a button the add(scrollingRegion) code is performed ,and he can see some row of information ,When user click on each row the menu is displayed ... If you have idea plz help

Comment: Sounds the problem is in ur customField, which your are using like a button i think, Have you properly overridden the fieldChangeNotify() method, in case you are using the CustomField as button?

Comment: No Adil, I am not using custom field as a button ,There is a button say(btnShow) in my app and a vertical field manager,My customField is a calss which extends ListField implements ListFieldCallback and there is a table row manager and different row(in a single row there is 4 listfields) are dynamically populated using a for loop .And the newly created customField Object is adding to the verticalfield manager and finally vertical field manager is adding to the main screen.

Comment: Ok i got it. Now tell me what type of action you want to perform when the user clicks at any row of your listfield..?

Comment: No any action take place when user clicks  listfield.Now It showing the menu

Comment: @AdilSoomro I am facing same issue but your answer not resolving my issue.. still facing same... :/