# Blackberry popup menu appear on Button click event

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a problem that popup menu appear when I click a button field. I will solve it by using Buttonfield.consumeclick but it also appears on RichTextField focus. How can I solve this? I am overriding RichTextField method, and that is the reason the popup menu appears.

Comment: The stack overflow link may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918778/avoid-showing-menu-on-button-click

Comment: Is a pop-up menu appearing when you give RichTextField focus? Is that the problem?

Comment: no i cant set focus.It automatically appear while creating richtextfield

Answer (score 2):

```
ButtonField c = new ButtonField("button", FIELD_LEFT | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK) {
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        Status.show("Button has clicked");
        // write your code.
        return true;
    }
}
```